# Parse error while writing a code

Tags: php, parsing

Please help,

> Error

**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in C:\xampp\htdocs\ecommerce\core\init.php on line 3**

> My Code

```
<?php
$db = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','root','','kidsshowroom')
if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo 'Database Connection failed with the following errors: '.mysqli_connect_error();
  die();
}
?>
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a semicolon, new code:

```
<?php
$db = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','root','','kidsshowroom');
if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo 'Database Connection failed with the following errors: '.mysqli_connect_error();
    die();
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!! Your solution worked.

Comment: Hey, if you could mark as solution, it'd help a lot.  Click the green tick mark.